# Typescript: No intellisense support for referenced class

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, intellisense

Following is an example code, it seems that intellisense doesn't recognize the `'exposedMethod'` when the class `'First'` is referenced in class `'Second'`.

Is this not supported by Intellisense or am I missing something?

```
class First{
    exposedMethod=()=>{

    }
}

class Second{
    firstClass;
    constructor(firstClass:First)
    {
        firstClass = firstClass;
    }

    someFunction=()=>{
        this.firstClass.exposedMethod();    //No intellisense support here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a type to your member

```
class Second{
    // instead of this
    // firstClass;
    // we should use this
    firstClass:First; // here
    constructor(firstClass:First)
    {
        // here we should assign this.firstClass 
        this.firstClass = firstClass;
    }
```

But the most suitable way, I'd say, is to use some syntax sugar coming with TS compiler

```
class Second{
    //  this syntax (protected, private, public) will do behind the same as above
    constructor(protected firstClass:First)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Whoa! didn't realize this. Thanks a lot